# How can a chat discussion be deleted

Tags: discussion, support, chat

In January, I was invited into a 2 person chat to discuss deeper a question I'd posed on SE. Now that chat is showing up in google search (on the 1st page, no less) and I'd prefer it to not be publicly available.

How does on delete or make the chat private?

Comment: A moderator would have to delete the room afaik.

Comment: @Bart, Any idea how to get a moderator's attention?

Comment: Just leave this here. One of them is bound to notice.

Comment: You can also select any message in the chatroom, click it and chose "Flag for moderator" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the chat room. Google should catch up eventually.

In general, you did the right thing by coming here. You can also flag a message in the room for moderator attention as mentioned in the comments, or email us via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Interestingly, I do not see Flag for Moderator anywhere. Thank you for deleting.

Comment: @DavidC Yeah, it's not very discoverable. You gotta click on the arrow  that appears on the left when you hover over a message.

Comment: Except for the starred messages, there were only 2 selectable items. Permalink and Feedback (I think). None of the few left sided arrows that appeared had the Flag for Moderator link. Is that because of the type of chat room the other participant created?

Comment: @DavidC Hmm. Might also be because the room got frozen for inactivity. I'm not really sure. Ah well, at least it's all settled now either way. :)